# BroadcastReceiver doesn't stop a thread

Tags: android

I do an BrodcastReceiver to speak the message: Receiving Call, while phone ringing.

Code of BroadcastReceiver to:

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    cont = context;
    tts = new Speak(cont);

    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE")) {
        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {

            incoming_number = intent.getExtras().getString(
                    "incoming_number");

            falador = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (!this.isInterrupted()) {
                            while (true) {
                                sleep(5000);
                                h.post(repeater);
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            falador.start();

        } else {
            if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                    TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {

                h.removeCallbacks(repeater);
                falador.interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But, the event IDLE doesn't stop the thread. Can you help me?

Thanks, 
Mateus

Comment: are you sure that your thread is running before interrupting it? perhaps it didnt run at all. Do some logging to see this

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```java
     falador = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
                        sleep(5000);
                        h.post(repeater);
                    }                        
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
     };
```

Then when you interrupt it will stop the thread

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but needs an answer. `BroadcastReceiver`s run on the main thread of the application process and `onReceive` method has a very short life time. You can think that Android system creates and runs and destroys an object of type of this receiver in the background:

```
BroadcastReceiver receiver = new YourReceiver();
receiver.onReceive(context, intent);
System.gc();
```

After this method finishes, related object (receiver) becomes susceptible to garbage collection. That means anything created/started/connected to this receiver can be killed immediately by the system. So you shouldn't (actually must not) do any asynchronous operation in the `onReceive` method. [Receiver Lifecyle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle) and [onReceive(context, intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) emphasize about this situation.