# Cancel button on Notification to remove Notification

Tags: android, multithreading, notifications, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a Notification that has a `Progress Bar` and a `Cancel` button. I am using Thread to increment the Progress Bar and the Cancel button is supposed to clear the notification.

Here's the code for Notification

```
    remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.customnotification);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocationBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("CancelServiceAndNotification","CancelServiceAndNotification");
    intent.putExtra("ID",1);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(),
       0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.bCancel, pendingIntent);
```

Code for incrementing Progress Bar using Thread

```
     thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int incr;
            for(incr = 0;incr<=100;incr+=10){
                remoteViews.setProgressBar(R.id.progressBar, 100, incr, false);
                if(cancelNotification){

                }
                notificationManager.notify(1,notification);
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (Exception e){

                }

            }
            notificationManager.cancel(1);
        }
    });
    thread.start();
```

In Broadcast Receiver, I am trying to cancel the notification using

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancel(ID);
```

The problem is that when I click on `Cancel` button the notification disappear for a second but then appear again, may be due to the thread still running. How to destroy the thread from broadcast Receiver class? What should I do to remove the notification on `cancel` button click ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop the thread you should interrupt it, for example when receiving "CancelServiceAndNotification" in your `BroadcastReceiver` you can call :

```
thread.interrupt();
```

Then, in your run() method :

```
    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
        // we were interrupted, should stop immediately
        return;
    }
```

If thread is interrupted while sleeping it will throw `InterruptedException` and clear interrupted flag, so in your case **it is very important** that you return from `run()` when catching `InterruptedException` :

```
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // we were interrupted, should stop immediately
        return;
    }
```

And you should cancel notification the same way you do :

```
// make sure you pass 1 as id here as you use it for notify()
notificationManager.cancel(1);
```

That should work.

However, it is strongly not recommended to update UI from non-main thread (which you do from you custom thread when calling `remoteViews.setProgressBar`).

I recommend using custom `AsyncTask` for doing background job in `doInBackground` (instead of your `run()` method and updating progress of your notification in its `onProgressUpdate`.
You can cancel `AsyncTask` by calling `cancel()` on it in a similar way you `interrupt()` a thread as shown above.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried your method but `Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()` is not working i.e. I interrupted the thread in `broadcastReceiver` and put a log in the `if()` but that is never called.

Comment: You should check `isInterrpted()` *inside* the loop in your run() method. Also, **very important** to stop/return when catching `InterruptedException` (please see my update above)

Comment: I am updating my question with the code that you suggested but it is still not working. Please see if i am doing something wrong.

Comment: Sorry i posted comment without refreshing the edit that you made. It is working now thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }
```

Comment: What am i supposed to understand from your answer?

Comment: The problem is that when I click on Cancel button the notification disappear for a second but then appear again, may be due to the thread still running... try to stop the thread once its done

Comment: how to do it from the broadcast receiver class?

Comment: take a look.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907643/broadcastreceiver-doesnt-stop-a-thread